# LDAP binding error

Tags: command-line, ldap, active-directory

I have a secure LDAP configured on a Active Directory.

I am trying to query it using the `ldapsearch` command on Ubuntu.

Following are dummy details:

```
Domain Name: dc=qwerty,dc=com 
LDAP Server: ldap_server.qwerty.com
LDAP Type: AD
Query User Name: ldapuser@qwerty.com
Password:Qwerty_12345
Port Number: 636 
Admin Group Name: abc_admin
```

When I try to execute following command :

```
`ldapsearch -x -W name=ldapuser@qwerty.com -h ldap_server.qwerty.com`
```

I am asked for password, but after entering correct password I get following error
Enter LDAP Password:
extended LDIF

```
LDAPv3
base <> (default) with scope subtree
filter: name=ldapuser@qwerty.com
requesting: ALL

search result
search: 2
result: 1 Operations error
text: 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0907E9, comment: In order to perform this opera
 tion a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v2580

numResponses: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using and amdin account you may be missing the -D.

This is a page I have used in the past for examples. Might help.

https://devconnected.com/how-to-search-ldap-using-ldapsearch-examples/

As user admin.

$ ldapsearch -x -b "dc=devconnected,dc=com" -H ldap://192.168.178.29 -D "cn=admin,dc=devconnected,dc=com" -W